# Updating lines in Excel when changes to S3 occur

Tags: excel, python-3.x, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

In a project I am running an AWS Sagemaker Jupyter notebook instance that heavily interacts with files (gathering, converting, computing, interacting) and after every step the files are moved from folder to folder to prepare for the next interaction. I was wondering if there was any way to set some form of chart (like excel) that creates/updates a row when a file enters a folder. The charts end goal is to be used as some form of tracker, to see what stage all the different files are in.

Examples of how the desired chart should look like below

[Chart Style 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOnSH.png)

[Chart Style 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoHiB.png)

Comment: Where do you envisage such a chart to be displayed? In the Jupyter notebook, or a web page? Is it only one flow of files, or might there be multiple flows simultaneously? Can you mock-up an example? There could be many ways to do this, but it depends on where & what!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Preferably a web page or something similar to that, we would want to monitor the chart outside of the notebook once the automation of the notebook is complete. Ideally, the Jupyter notebook runs without manual assistance and the status of the files can be monitored externally from this chart.

Answer (score 0):

One way in which you could achieve this is by pushing the data programmatically to a central Google Spreadsheet and use the data from there to create charts.

You could use the [GSpread Library](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) in Python to push the data after certain steps in your code are run successfully. We use this extensively to push data to Google Sheets every day.

You would need to check the [API rate limits](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits) enforced by Google Cloud which can be increased as per your requirements.

Comment: I was looking into this method upon your recommendation, unfortunately my company doesn't sanction the use of google docs or sheets or google products like the such.